# Android Things blank screen in touch screen 3.2 inch

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi, iot, touchscreen

I tried use the touch screen 3.2 inch in my raspberry with android things, but is not working!!
I searched a lot, but nothing help me!
**This is my original config.txt:**

```
kernel=u-boot-dtok.bin<br>
framebuffer_depth=16<br>
dtparam=i2c_arm=on<br>
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan-with-clk,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4<br>
dtparam=spi=on<br>
dtparam=audio=on<br>
start_x=1<br>
Tell U-boot to always use the "serial0" interface for the console, which is<br>
set to whichever uart (uart0 or uart1) is set to the header pins. This doesn't<br>
interfere with the uart selected for Bluetooth.dtoverlay=chosen-serial0<br>
Enable skip-init on the UART interfaces, so U-Boot doesn't attempt to<br>
re-initialize them.dtoverlay=rpi-uart-skip-init<br>
Uncomment to disable serial port on headers, use GPIO14 and GPIO15<br>
as gpios and to allow the core_freq to change at runtime.enable_uart=1
core_freq=400<br>
```

This is my raspberry with the touch screen

[image]

Comment: The screen is blank when turn on. The resolution is 320X240.

Comment: Do you get any display blinking when the power supply is turned on? Also, can tell the exact display model (preferably providing a link)? And in addition, do you have a `Raspberry Pi 3`?

Comment: Can you provide as much the display info as possible?